# How to just pass variadic arguments through

Tags: swift, swift5

```
struct Data: ExpressibleByDictionaryLiteral {
    let storage: KeyValuePairs<String, Int>
    
    init(dictionaryLiteral elements: (String, Int)...) {
        storage = KeyValuePairs(dictionaryLiteral: elements)
    }
}
```

Compilation error:

> Cannot pass array of type '[(String, Int)]' as variadic arguments of
> type '(String, Int)'

I know that it's all about "splatting" which is not in the language yet (when will it be, by the way?) and that there are a plenty workarounds here to initialize the struct.
But it's so weird. I'm getting elements exactly in the form  KeyValuePairs initializer needed, and I can't just pass it through directly!

Comment: How do you pass arguments? And what do you expect?

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini "How do you pass arguments?" that's exactly what I'm asking in the question))) I want to know how can I do it)))

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini I mean how to pass data from the initializer of Data struct to the initializer of KeyValuePairs.

Comment: Voted down for going off-track without a clear question. I recommend stick to solving your actual problem in your other question, and deleting this one.

Comment: First make your struct generic and add two generic types <Key, Value>, then add a type alias for the key value element `typealias Element = (key: Key, value: Value)` and change your storage declaration to `[Element]`. Know you can use a generic initializer `init(dictionaryLiteral elements: (Key, Value)...) {` and simply assign elements to storage `storage = elements`

Comment: Kkkkkkkkkkk *Now

Comment: @Jessy I've solved my problem already by using [(String, Int)] instead of KeyValuePairs<String, Int> but my goal is also to understand and master swift language :)

Comment: Side note don't name your struct `Data` if you do that you would need to reference Swift native `Data` type adding `Foundation.Data`  all over your code.

Answer (score 0):

#### How to just pass variadic arguments:

like this:

```
Data(dictionaryLiteral: ("key", 1))
// or 
Data(dictionaryLiteral: ("key1", 1), ("key2", 2))
```

As you can see, you can pass any number of variables as the first parameter.

## But

seems like you are trying to pass an `array` to the initializer, If so, you should have an initializer for that like:

```
init(dictionaryLiteral elements: [(String, Int)]) {
    storage = KeyValuePairs(dictionaryLiteral: elements)
}
```

then you can pass an array too:

```
Data(dictionaryLiteral: [("key1", 1), ("key2", 2)])
```

---

## How to make it compile?

<sub>(And work as expected)</sub>

Since Swift is not supporting **Splatting** yet and you are trying to implement a `Dictionary`, you should reconsider the structure of the `struct`. So the storage should be a `Dictionary`:

```
let storage: [String: Int]
```

Then you can implement a second initializer I discussed above and then use it inside the required initializer like:

```
struct Data: ExpressibleByDictionaryLiteral {
    let storage: [String: Int]

    init(dictionaryLiteral elements: (String, Int)...) {
        self.init(dictionary: elements.reduce(into: [Key: Value](), { (result, tuple) in
            result[tuple.0] = tuple.1
        }))
    }

    init(dictionary: [Key: Value]) {
        storage = dictionary
    }
}
```

Comment: The code in my question doesn't compile. No matter how to pass data to Data struct, the "storage" property will not be created appropriately.